# How can i project certain child elements of an injected content

Tags: angular, angular-content-projection

i want to understand if i can selectively project certain children of an injected html block.
lets assume i have a code block

```
<layout>
   <div>
      <h1>This is header 1</h1>
      <h2 class="projectThis">This is header 2</h2>
   </div>
</layout>
```

the layout component is an angular component with ng-content

```
<layout>
<ng-content select=".projectThis"></ng-content>
</layout>
```

but this does not work. angular does not see deep inside the projected contents. is there a way to do this.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Where are you expecting it to project to?

Comment: i am expecting to project inside the layout component
my layout component looks like this
<layout><ng-content select=".projectThis"></ng-content>